# How to get the previous row value for a field when it is empty/null

Tags: sql, oracle, hive

I have transaction table with the data as below.

| acct_updt_tm | acct_id | acct_eff_dt | acct_cncl_dt | acct_canc_cd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-24 | 9873456 |  |  |  |
| 2023-10-14 | 9873456 | 2020-06-11 | 2023-12-01 | 01 |
| 2023-10-24 | 5567341 |  |  |  |
| 2023-10-14 | 5567341 | 2021-05-14 | 2022-12-12 | 01 |

Need to write a query where if the value of acct_eff_dt column is null, the output should display the previous non-null value for the field using a windowing function row_number to pull only latest updated record for the account as shown below.

**Expected Output**

| acct_updt_tm | acct_id | acct_eff_dt | acct_cncl_dt | acct_canc_cd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-24 | 9873456 | 2020-06-11 |  |  |
| 2023-10-24 | 5567341 | 2021-05-14 |  |  |

The above are the two records with the latest acct_updt_tm but does not have acct_eff_dt populated in original table. Output should populate the value for these records

`select * from (select acct_updt_tm,acct_id,acct_eff_dt,acct_cncl_dt,acct_canc_cd, row_number() over (partition by acct_id order by acct_updt_tm desc) as rnk) a where a.rnk=1`

Please help how to modify the query to get the requirement.

Comment: Oracle or Hive? Please post some sample data **as text** and desired output for it

Comment: @astentx I have added the sample data and desired output for the same. Please suggest

Answer (score 3):

Code you posted looks like Oracle. If that's so, `LAG` analytic function might be one option.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (acct_updt_tm, acct_id, acct_eff_dt) as
  2    (select to_date('2023-10-24 23:04:35', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 56, null              from dual union all
  3     select to_date('2023-10-14 19:34:11', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 56, date '2020-06-11' from dual union all
  4     select to_date('2023-10-14 19:12:03', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 56, date '2020-06-10' from dual
  5    )
```

Query:

```
  6  select acct_updt_tm, acct_id,
  7    nvl(acct_eff_dt, lag(acct_eff_dt) ignore nulls over (partition by acct_id order by acct_updt_tm)) acct_eff_dt
  8  from test
  9  order by acct_updt_tm desc;

ACCT_UPDT_TM           ACCT_ID ACCT_EFF_DT
------------------- ---------- -------------------
2023-10-24 23:04:35         56 2020-06-11 00:00:00
2023-10-14 19:34:11         56 2020-06-11 00:00:00
2023-10-14 19:12:03         56 2020-06-10 00:00:00

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]**, based on your comment: if you want to fetch the *latest* values per each `acct_id`, use `max` aggregate function:

```
SQL> with test (acct_updt_tm, acct_id, acct_eff_dt) as
  2    (select date '2023-10-24', 56, null              from dual union all
  3     select date '2023-10-14', 56, date '2020-06-11' from dual union all
  4     --
  5     select date '2023-10-24', 41, null              from dual union all
  6     select date '2023-10-14', 41, date '2021-05-14' from dual
  7    )
  8  select acct_id, max(acct_updt_tm) acct_updt_tm, max(acct_eff_dt) acct_eff_dt
  9  from test
 10  group by acct_id
 11  order by acct_id desc;

   ACCT_ID ACCT_UPDT_ ACCT_EFF_D
---------- ---------- ----------
        56 2023-10-24 2020-06-11
        41 2023-10-24 2021-05-14

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the logic. But if I have multiple ACCT_ID's in the table and if I have to pull the latest ID, can you please assist what needs to be done in that case

Comment: Have a look at edited answer.

Comment: Just for clarity and completeness: [Hive doesn't allow](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) `ignore nulls` in `lag`, but it may be replaced with `last_value(<expr>, true) over(partition by ... order by ...) rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding` to calculate the same. `max` is suitable for this particular case because `order by` expression and required expression are the same, but `first_value` may be applicable if they are different